# how to pass jquery .last().after() value to php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i need help

i have a code of jquery that is auto generated by a press of button but i dont know how to pass it to php

here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cnt = 2;
    $("#anc_add").click(function() {
        $('#tbl2 tr').last().after('<tr><td><textarea name="c16_2" id="c16_2" >PO Item [' + cnt + ']</textarea></td><td><input type="date" name="date4_2" id="date4_2" ></input></td><td><textarea style="border: none; width: 100%;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" name="d16_2" id="d16_2" cols="10"rows="3" ></textarea></td><td><textarea style="border: none; width: 100%;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;"  name="e16_2" id="e16_2" cols="10"rows="3"></textarea></td><td><textarea style="border: none; width: 100%;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" name="f16_2" id="f16_2" cols="10"rows="3"></textarea></td><td><select style="border: none; width: 100%; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;"  name="g16_2" id="g16_2" cols="10" rows="3"><option value="Not Started">Not Started</option><option value="On Track">On Track</option><option value="Delayed">Delayed</option><option value="Concern">Concern</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></td><td><textarea style="border: none; width: 100%;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" name="h16_2" id="h16_2" cols="10"rows="3"></textarea></td><td><textarea style="border: none; width: 100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" name="i16_2" id="i16_2" cols="10"rows="3"></textarea></td><td><textarea style="border: none; width: 100%;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" name="j16_2" id="j16_2" cols="10"rows="3"></textarea></td></tr>');
        cnt++;
    });


    $("#anc_rem").click(function() {
        if ($('#tbl2 tr').size() > 3) {
            $('#tbl2 tr:last-child').remove();
            cnt--;


        } else {
            alert('One row should be present in table');
        }
    });

});
```

i've tried ajax

```
$(function(post()) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'p1process.php',
        data: ({
            tbl2: "300"
        }),
        data: ({
            tbl3: "300"
        }),
        data: ({
            tbl5: "300"
        }),
        data: ({
            tbl6: "300"
        }),
    });
});
```

Comment: you can use ajax or form submit

Comment: not working i've tried so many time

Comment: tried what?include in the OP

Comment: i've tried ajax  
  $(function(post()){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'p1process.php',
      data: ({tbl2:"300"}),
   data: ({tbl3:"300"}),
   data: ({tbl5:"300"}),
   data: ({tbl6:"300"}),
     
    });
  });

Comment: try this `$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {

        tbl2: "300",
        tbl3: "300",
        tbl5: "300",
        tbl6: "300"
    }
    success: function(data) {

    }

});`

Comment: You can not have multiple data objects.... Objects with the same key will just override them....

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'p1process.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {

        tbl2: "300",
        tbl3: "300",
        tbl5: "300",
        tbl6: "300"
    }
    success: function(data) {

    }

});
```

Use this

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to send input data. Example below

```
$(function () {
    $('formname' ).on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'p1process.php',
        data: $('formname').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert('form is submited');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```